# Unicode to string conversion in Java

Tags: java, unicode, string

I am building a language, a toy language. The syntax `\#0061` is supposed to convert the given Unicode to an character:

```
String temp = yytext().subtring(2);
```

Then after that try to append `'\u'` to the string, I noticed that generated an error.

I also tried to `"\\" + "u" + temp;` this way does not do any conversion.

I am basically trying to convert Unicode to a character by supplying only `'0061'` to a method, help.

Comment: Note that 16 bits (4 hex digits) is not enough to represent all characters in Unicode. In java "\u1234" maps to a code point unit in UTF-16, which is not the same as a character.

Comment: Addendum: In fact it's the java data type char that maps to UTF-16 code point units, not actual Unicode characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strip the '#' and use `Integer.parseInt("0061", 16)` to convert the hex digits to an `int`.  Then cast to a `char`.

(If you had implemented the lexer by hand, an alternatively would be to do the conversion on the fly as your lexer matches the unicode literal.  But on rereading the question, I see that you are using a lexer generator ... good move!)

Comment: Just curious: how did you spot that he's using a lexer?

Comment: @BalusC Because of `yytext`, a lex specific variable

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the particular codepoint to a `char`. You can do that with a little help of regex:

```
String string = "blah #0061 blah";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\#((?i)[0-9a-f]{4})").matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()) {
    int codepoint = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1), 16);
    string = string.replaceAll(matcher.group(0), String.valueOf((char) codepoint));
}

System.out.println(string); // blah a blah
```

**Edit** as per the comments, if it is a single token, then just do:

```
String string = "0061";
char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(string, 16);
System.out.println(c); // a
```

Comment: Erm ... you don't want to implement a lexical analyser using Java regex pattern matching.

Comment: I need something like the first example you posted. I ran the code making the pattern changes as I need them however the ReplaceAll doesn't replace anything. The string is the same as the original string :(

Comment: @Eric: press `Ask Question` button on right top to ask a question on which you would like to get answers.

Answer (score 2):

> i am basically trying to convert
>   unicode to a character by supplying
>   only '0061' to a method, help.

```
char fromUnicode(String codePoint) {
  return (char)  Integer.parseInt(codePoint, 16);
}
```

You need to handle bad inputs and such, but that will work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`\uXXXX` is an escape sequence.  Before execution it has already been converted into the actual character value, its not "evaluated" in anyway at runtime.

What you probably want to do is define a mapping from your `#XXXX` syntax to Unicode code points and cast them to `char`.