# Converting to utf-8 in java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, normalization, unicode-normalization

I just have the string `\u0130smail` and I want to convert it to 
İsmail and also convert

```
  \u0130 --> İ   
  \u00E7 --> ç
```

I tried

```
String str = "\u0130smail";
sysout(str);
```

and it worked, but whenever I get the string `"\u0130smail"` from the DB or the internet it doesn't give the correct result.

```
static String deneme(String string){
    String string2 = null;

    try {
        byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
        string2 = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    }
    return string2;
}
```

didn't work either.

Comment: Doing this: `byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
    string2 = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");` does not do anything. How did you build your `string` argument?

Comment: What do you get as output? That'd be very helpful in determining the problem.

Comment: I found this relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934842/unicode-to-string-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings `"\u0130smail"` and `"İsmail"` are absolutely the same from the language standpoint. If you mean that you get a string `"\\u0130smail"` (note that I've escaped the backslash), then you will have to find the pattern of the unicode code points and convert them to normal unicode letters or just print the number, whichever you need. Regular expressions could help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the existing string to bytes and back again isn't going to help you. You need to look at the exact characters in the string you've got - and work out *how* you got them.

I suggest you print out the integer value of each character in the string *as* an integer (ideally in hex) to find out exactly what you've got... then trace it back as far as you can, to work out what's going wrong.