# Number of characters in Java String

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, thai

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: length of string when using unicode overline to display square roots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704426/java-length-of-string-when-using-unicode-overline-to-display-square-roots)

How do I get number of Unicode characters in a String?

Given a `char[]` of Thai characters:

```
[อ, ภ, ิ, ช, า, ต, ิ]
```

This comes out in String as:
อภิชาติ

`String.length()` returns 7. I understand there are (technically) 7 characters, but I need a method that would return me 5. That is the exact number of character spaces represented on screen.

Comment: You could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704426/java-length-of-string-when-using-unicode-overline-to-display-square-roots

Comment: This maybe of some help to you. 
[count chars in a unicode string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298059/how-to-count-characters-in-a-unicode-string-in-c

Comment: @Mukul, the link you offered is explicitly in C, not Java (to which this question refers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you just want to not count the unicode marks as separate characters;

```
static boolean isMark(char ch)
{
    int type = Character.getType(ch);
    return type == Character.NON_SPACING_MARK ||
           type == Character.ENCLOSING_MARK ||
           type == Character.COMBINING_SPACING_MARK;
}
```

which can be used as;

```
String olle = "อภิชาติ";
int count = 0;

for(int i=0; i<olle.length(); i++)
{
    if(!isMark(olle.charAt(i)))
        count++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

and returns '5'.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt the solution posted to this question here:

[Unicode to string conversion in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934842/unicode-to-string-conversion-in-java)

By stripping the '#' character and counting the remaining characters in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `java.text.BreakIterator` to find the gaps between the graphemes ("visual characters") and count them. Here's an example:

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;

..

int graphemeLength(String str) {
    BreakIterator iter = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance();
    iter.setText(str);

    int count = 0;
    while (iter.next() != BreakIterator.DONE) count++;

    return count;
}
```

Now `graphemeLength("อภิชาติ")` will return 5.