# Facebook JSON locale

Tags: java, facebook, api

Good day.

I make a request to facebook API to retrieve friend list.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/?access_token=CAAB03LXvJxgBAFZCwCnZBIgk...MMAZD&locale=en_UK
```

And i got a response JSON with my friends but those friends who has cyrillic characters in their names look like this

```
{
         "name": "\u0410\u043d\u043d\u0430 \u042f\u043a\u043e\u0432\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0430",
         "id": "100000762004565"
}
```

So i tried change locale to ru_RU, but it didn`t help, furthermore ru_RU changes some english names to that weird bytecode.

Please help me retrieve cyrillic names. Thx;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have there is a String created of a bunch of unicode characters.
printing them will preduce "Анна Яковлева".

if you want to get this as cyrillic names you need to parse them as such.
try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1934860/1056359) for more information about parsing unicode in Java.